# Problems with KMM, compose and serialization

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I have KMM project with multiplatform compose.
kotlinVersion=1.8.10
agpVersion=8.0.1
composeVersion=1.4.0
kotlinxSerialization = "1.5.1"

While building I get an error:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CompilationException: Back-end: Please report this problem https://kotl.in/issue
C:/commonVM/multiplatform/aiprocessormodul/feature-response/src/commonMain/kotlin/pl/probs/feature_response/jsonStructure/BasicReport.kt:12:1
Problem with `@Serializable
data class BasicReport<T : Any?> {
  constructor(appInfo: String, LaunchKey: String, kpiResults: List<KpiResult>, kpiResultsWithoutManualProducts: JsonElement, startDate: JsonElement, status: String, userInfo: String, input: BasicReportInput?, output: BasicReportOutput<T>?) /* primary */ {
    super/*Any*/()
    /* <init>() */

  }
....
`
Details: kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin internal error: unable to transform declaration, see cause
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializerClassLowering.lower(SerializationLoweringExtension.kt:219)
```

Comment: Please make sure that all types you store in yours serializable class are also serializable.